# how to return two array list in JSON and view in data table rows using asp.net MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

RoleListand EmpListwe having two arraylist how to return two array list in JSON and how to view in data table rows.

I need to return `return Json(EmpList,RoleList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

```
[HttpPost]
        [MyExceptionHandler]
        public ActionResult ViewModules(int id)
        {
            Domain_Bind();
            dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
            userType type = new userType();
            List<ViewRoleModules> EmpList = type.GetRoleModulesViews(id);
            string sRptModuleIDs = string.Empty;
            foreach (ViewRoleModules emp in EmpList)
            {
                sRptModuleIDs += emp.ModuleID + ",";
            }
            if (sRptModuleIDs != "")
            {
                sRptModuleIDs = sRptModuleIDs.Remove(sRptModuleIDs.Length - 1, 1);
            }

            List<ViewRoleModules> RoleList;
            foreach (var rid in sRptModuleIDs.Split(','))
            {
                string RID = rid;
                RoleList = type.GetSiteRoleModulesViews(rid);
            }

            return Json(EmpList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

Scripts:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#DomainID").change(function () {

                var id = $(this).val();
                $("#example tbody tr").remove();

                $.ajax({

                    type: 'POST',

                    url: '@Url.Action("ViewModules")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { id: id },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var items = '';
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            $("#findValue").show();
                            var rows = "<tr>"
                            + "<td>" + i + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.ModuleName + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.Url + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.RoleName + "</td>"
                            + "</tr>";
                            $('#example tbody').append(rows);
                        });

                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                        alert("Message: " + r.Message);
                        alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
                        alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            })
        });
    </script>
```

Cshtml:

```
<table id="example" class="display table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>S#</th>
                                <th>Module Name</th>
                                <th>Url</th>
                                <th>Roles</th>
                                @*<th>Action</th>*@
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

in my code return only one array list..

I need to display to array list

```
public List<ViewRoleModules> GetRoleModulesViews(int id)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Admin"].ConnectionString))
            {
                List<ViewRoleModules> EmpList = new List<ViewRoleModules>();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("MEDEIL_Modules_SelectDomainModules", conn);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DomainID", id);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                conn.Open();
                da.Fill(dt);
                conn.Close();
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {

                    EmpList.Add(

                        new ViewRoleModules
                        {
                            ModuleID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ModuleID"]),
                            CompanyTypeID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CompanyTypeID"]),
                            DomainID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["DomainID"]),
                            ParentModuleID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ParentModuleID"]),
                            ModuleName = Convert.ToString(dr["ModuleName"]),
                            FolderName = Convert.ToString(dr["FolderName"] == DBNull.Value ? null : dr["FolderName"].ToString()),
                            Url = Convert.ToString(dr["Url"]),
                            TabOrder = Convert.ToInt32(dr["TabOrder"]),
                            Style = Convert.ToString(dr["Style"]),
                            Status = Convert.ToString(dr["Status"]),
                            IsTab = Convert.ToString(dr["IsTab"]),
                            ApprovalProcess = Convert.ToString(dr["ApprovalProcess"]),
                            CreatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(dr["CreatedBy"] == DBNull.Value ? null : dr["CreatedBy"].ToString()),
                            CreatedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["CreatedDate"]),
                            ModifiedBy = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ModifiedBy"] == DBNull.Value ? null : dr["ModifiedBy"].ToString()),
                            ModifiedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ModifiedDate"] == DBNull.Value ? null : dr["ModifiedDate"].ToString())
                        }
                    );
                }

                return EmpList;
            }
        }


        public List<ViewRoleModules> GetSiteRoleModulesViews(string rid)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Admin"].ConnectionString))
            {
                List<ViewRoleModules> RoleList = new List<ViewRoleModules>();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("MEDEIL_SiteRoleModules_SelectOne", conn);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModuleID", Convert.ToInt32(rid));
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                conn.Open();
                da.Fill(dt);
                conn.Close();
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {

                    RoleList.Add(

                        new ViewRoleModules
                        {
                            RoleID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["RoleID"]),
                            RoleName = Convert.ToString(dr["RoleName"])

                        }
                    );
                }

                return RoleList;
            }
        }
```

Comment: you can do something like `return Json(new { empList = EmpList, roleList = RoleList }, , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` and access like `data.empList` and `data.roleList`

Comment: Note that inside the last foreach you override the value of `RoleList` on every iteration. Perhaps you want to add stuff to this list instead?

Comment: @Andrei yes RoleList is local variable so showing some error

Comment: Well, obviously you should initialize it. I would expect it be initialized with an empty list, and then add things on each iteration

Answer (score 0):

You can easily combine the two with an anonymous type:

```
var data = new {EmpList = EmpList, RoleList = RoleList};
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And on the client side just use the property you need:

```
success: function (data) {
    // do something with role list
    $.each(data.RoleList, function (i, item) {

    ...
    // do something else with employee list
    $.each(data.EmpList, function (i, item) {
```

Comment: List<ViewRoleModules> RoleList;  use of unassigned RoleList showing error

Comment: @IvinRaj, of course you should assign some value to it

Comment: List<ViewRoleModules> RoleList = new List<ViewRoleModules> (); i added in this code is it correct? @ Andrei

Comment: @IvinRaj, yes, assuming you also add some items into it later on

Comment: $.each(data.RoleList,  data.RoleList  in foreach function we can display the results as asingle row @Andrei

Answer (score 0):

you can try the simple way with dictionary.

```
     public ActionResult ViewModules(int id)
    {
        Domain_Bind();
        dynamic mymodel = new ExpandoObject();
        userType type = new userType();

         Dictionary<string, object> dList = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        List<ViewRoleModules> EmpList = type.GetRoleModulesViews(id);
        string sRptModuleIDs = string.Empty;
        foreach (ViewRoleModules emp in EmpList)
        {
            sRptModuleIDs += emp.ModuleID + ",";
        }
        if (sRptModuleIDs != "")
        {
            sRptModuleIDs = sRptModuleIDs.Remove(sRptModuleIDs.Length - 1, 1);
        }

        List<ViewRoleModules> RoleList;
        foreach (var rid in sRptModuleIDs.Split(','))
        {
            string RID = rid;
            RoleList = type.GetSiteRoleModulesViews(rid);
        }

        dList.Add("EmpList", EmpList);
        dList.Add("RoleList", RoleList);

        return Json(dList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

With the help of dictionary, you can bind n number of object together.

Comment: List<ViewRoleModules> RoleList; use of unassigned RoleList showing error

Comment: you can try with      List<ViewRoleModules> RoleList = new List<ViewRoleModules> ();    and     RoleList .Add(type.GetSiteRoleModulesViews(rid));

Comment: data rows  view how to call dList

Comment: @lvin Raj  EmpList.propertyName like EmpList.firstName

Comment: item.ModuleName is default am using if i change EmpList.ModuleName is can't get value